# Получение постов пользователя в Instagram по его имени?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Для работы использую API Instagram Basic Display.
Получил токен. Но там все запросы к media идут с использованием user id (+ какая то мутка с старыми id и новыми ).
Сейчас стоит вопрос как по имени юзера получить его ид и соответственно его посты/ленту?.
Ну или какой то другой рабочий способ.

Answer (score 0):

Я в своё время использовал [эту библиотеку](https://packagist.org/packages/raiym/instagram-php-scraper).

```php
<?php

$client = new \InstagramScraper\Instagram();

$posts = $client->getMedias('username');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post->getLink();
}
```

Comment: Да, тоже ее юзал, но к сожалению щас она выдает ошибку : Something went wrong. Please report issue. API инстаграм значительно поменялось и авторизации тоже ((.

Comment: А Вы пробовали обновлять библиотек до последней версии?

Comment: Да, с https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-java-scraper скачивал

Comment: попробуйте получить user_id через эндпоинт `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]`, а дальше через API Instagram Basic Display

Comment: Попробовал, почему то для https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search пишет что OAuthAccessTokenException The access_token provided is invalid. Для https://graph.instagram.com/ мой ид /media?fields=caption,media_type,media_url,username&access_token - все работает без проблем.

Comment: Но это еще не вся проблема, там щас есть старые и новые ид. Вот https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&query=juli (работает только если авторизирован) отдает json c "pk": "38978468111" но этот ид не возможно использовать с API Instagram Basic Display он требует новый вариант ид. А как его получить хз?

Comment: @PHPWork а через GET-зпрос `https://www.instagram.com/{USERNAME}/?__a=1` пробовали?

Comment: конечно, если не авторизирован то сразу форма авторизации.

Comment: @PHPWork странно. Вы точно в параметром `__a=1` пробовали? Сейчас в инкогнито открыл [https://www.instagram.com/juli/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/juli/?__a=1) - вижу настоящий json, `graphql.user.id` = `611332083`